# How to solve this in react?

Tags: reactjs

There are 16 boxes of color blue and if you click any box that's color turns into red. Maximum 2 boxes can be red and if you click any 3rd box then it truns into red and the first red  box turns into blue and so on...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Suraj! Please include the code you have written so far and what you are having issues with.

Comment: I've written the code but it didn't work that means whole 16 boxes color changes to red  so i deleted that .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./style.css";

const Box = ({ onPress, style }) => {
  return <div style={style} onClick={onPress} className="box" />;
};

export default function App() {
  /*
This is the main part of the app, here we create a state called checked which 
will hold the last two indexes of checked boxes, and based on that index, 
we will conditionally set the background color of the Box component to either 
red or blue. 
*/
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState([]);
  let array = Array.from({ length: 16 }, () => 0);
  // console.log(array);
  return (
    <div className="container">
      {array?.map((_, index) => (
        <Box
          key={index}
          onPress={() => {
            let temp = [...checked];
            if (temp.length === 2) {
              temp.shift();
            }
            if (!temp.includes(index)) setChecked([...temp, index]);
          }}
          style={{ backgroundColor: checked.includes(index) ? "red" : "blue" }}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Full example: [Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-beuk77?file=src%2FApp.js)

Comment: Great! it works bro but i need some explanation about this code(if u don't mind)

Comment: it's very simple, we are creating a one-state for holding the clicked boxes, and if the length of checked boxes becomes greater than 2, then we will just remove the first index and add the newest clicked index. I have left one small bug as it is, intentionally, have fun solving it.